# Symmetric editing mode for faces

Tags: python, scripting, edit-mode, faces, mirror

I'm trying to create a simply script which orients a face towards the other (like a mirror) using the middle point which coords are calculated between their normals positions.

I didn't find a way to do with the provided tools, the only way was manually to rotate around its normal one face (eg commands R Y 35), taking into account the rotation angle and axis, and then doing the same but with minus angle (eg commands R Y 35 -)

Reading script api i found polygons but every polygons has only its normal coords and there is no way to rotate it.

Someone could help 8maybe i missed some tool/editing mode)? Thanx in advance.

[image: Behavior]

Comment: A common method for this is to only model one half and  use a mirror modifier to generate  the reflection side..  Script Example here re rotating faces https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165705/15543  To make a mirror rotation multiply original side rotation matrix  by the scale matrix that defines the mirror. eg mirror x about 0 is `Matrix.Diagonal((-1, 1, 1))` _ie_ scaling by -1 in x to make mirror loc of `(x, y, z) => (-x, y, z)`

Comment: .. It's possible this _is_ what you want, if so, sorry to interrupt.. but a rotation here will distort the edges which are _along_ the extrusion. To maintain those edges' original radial direction, you would slide the inside edges of the top faces down them, which you could do simultaneously.